# GCloud: can't import datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Well I'm trying to use Datastore in a personal project using the Google App Engine. Though, I can't import the datastore module, no matter how hard I try.

I've been using the online console during the whole time (in order to avoid to have to solve problems first on my PC and then on GCloud...)

So, I'm using

```
from google.cloud import datastore
```

Unfortunately, that's not working at all. The last error I have is

```
ImportError: No module named google.protobuf
```

But before I had things like `Can't import Datastore.`

What I did was removing the integrality of /lib, and reinstalling every dependancy with pip. Here is my `requirements.txt`:

```
# This requirements file lists all third-party dependencies for this project.
#
# Run 'pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib/' to install these dependencies
# in `lib/` subdirectory.
#
# Note: The `lib` directory is added to `sys.path` by `appengine_config.py`.
Flask==0.10
google.cloud==0.25.0
protobuf==3.3.0
```

(The last line was added to try to resolve the last error I got). Before having this error, I got

Also, a little clarification question: I've seen (while looking for answers) people using `gcloud` and some using `google.cloud`. What's the difference? What should I use?

Also, `pip show google.cloud` shows nothing.

What am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if anyone is wondering, here's how I solved the problem. What fixed it was changing the Flask version to 0.12 (don't know why, but that's what happened).

I deleted `lib` to be sure I was starting from scratch. Then, I used this `requirements.txt` file:

```
Flask==0.12
google-cloud==0.25.0
click==5.1
```

(`click` is needed by Flask 0.12).